# Adding Applicant Info in SQL using Class object

Tags: c#, sql-server

I would like to ask i have a class of Applicants

```
public class Applicant_info
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime ApplicantDateofRegistration { get; set; }

    public long ApplicantID { get; set; }

    public string ApplicantName { get; set; }

    public string ApplicantFatherName { get; set; }
}
```

my objective is to Insert List of Applicants object in to SQL Database using Stored Procedure , How can I achieve my objective?

```
protected void btnAddNewApplicant_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        apprepo = new Repositories.ApplicantRepository();
        List<Applicant_info> appinfo = new List<Applicant_info>();
        appinfo[0].ApplicantDateofRegistration = Convert.ToDateTime(dateofreg.Text);
        appinfo[0].ApplicantID = Convert.toInt64(txtID.text);
        appinfo[0].ApplicantName = txtapplicantName.Text;
        appinfo[0].ApplicantFatherName = txtsonof.Text;
    }
```

Do I need to make a custome type in SQL? Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options available, one option is to make use of a stored procedure with a table valued parameter. It will require that you create a custom table value type in the database. It will also require that you copy your list into a .net Datatable. This is a good option if you are certain that your table and class structures will never change, otherwise it can get a bit painful to maintain.

I prefer simply serializing the list as an xml and then pass the xml as a parameter to your stored procedure. It is a little bit less sensitive to minor changes in your class structure (such as adding new field members). The following example shows what the implementation in C# looks like:

```
    private void SqlExportApplicantInfo(List<Applicant_info> applicants)
    {
        const string storedProcedureName = @"UploadApplicants";  // Your sql stored procedure name here
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

        connectionBuilder.ApplicationName = "AppName";      // Set your application name here
        connectionBuilder.ConnectTimeout = 30;
        connectionBuilder.DataSource = "(local)";           // Set your server name here
        connectionBuilder.InitialCatalog = "SimplyData";    // Set your database here
        connectionBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;

        string connectionString = connectionBuilder.ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(storedProcedureName, connection))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Applicant_info>));
                    XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    serializer.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, applicants);
                    memoryStream = (MemoryStream)xmlTextWriter.BaseStream;
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;

                    SqlXml applicantsXml = new SqlXml(memoryStream);
                    SqlParameter parameter = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@applicantsXml", applicantsXml);
                    parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Xml;

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Failed to upload applicant list to sql.", exception);
            }
        }

    }
```

The following stored procedure example shows how you can evaluate the generated xml in SQL Server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UploadApplicants
(
    @applicantsXml XML
) 
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Applicants]
    (
        Id
        ,ApplicantDateofRegistration
        ,ApplicantID
        ,ApplicantName
        ,ApplicantFatherName
    )
    SELECT 
         Applicants.Info.value('Id[1]', 'INT') AS Id
        ,Applicants.Info.value('ApplicantDateofRegistration[1]', 'DATETIME') AS ApplicantDateofRegistration
        ,Applicants.Info.value('ApplicantID[1]', 'INT') AS ApplicantID
        ,Applicants.Info.value('ApplicantName[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS ApplicantName
        ,Applicants.Info.value('ApplicantFatherName[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS ApplicantFatherName
    FROM    
        @applicantsXml.nodes('ArrayOfApplicant_info/Applicant_info') Applicants(Info);

END
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways:

You can use a ORM framework like `LINQ-SQL` or `EntityFramework` to have it simple and straight forward. if you want to use ADO.NET code for this then you can define

1. stored procedure to insert data to DB which will take all the properties as parameter.
2. call the stored procedure with the property data from the `Applicant_info` object.

Comment: thats a problem i am forced not to use any framework

Comment: @M.Nabeel, you can write ado.net code then by yourself and you are not restricted to use ORM framework.